# Shard queries timing out - Sharding status not available

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Queries to one of our shards are regularly timing out with the following error:

“sharding status of collection db.collection is not currently available for description and needs to be recovered from the config server”

I’ve spent a sizeable amount of time scouring the internet but the only references I find are to test bug reports in Jira.

Has anyone experienced similar issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by mismatched versions between shards. Once all were upgraded to within 1 minor version, the message disappeared.